# Document inside my content script is the same after clicking (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

It seeems that my content script `document.URL` always has the same value even when I click on a random `<a href` link.

In the below function in the content script, I have a function called `performclick()` which finds a random link on the current document, then clicks it.

Now shouldn't the next time I call `performclick()`, I get another `document` object? i.e. document of the currently focused active tab?

Like when I click a link on the main page and it opens a new tab with another website loaded in it, then I need the content script to give me the `document` of this new tab that has the clicked website link loaded in it.

But some how I always keep getting the `document` object of the same main page.
Please help

**Manifest**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "OSP Updater",
"version": "1.0.0",
"content_scripts": [{
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
}],
"permissions": [
"background", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "tabs", "<all_urls>"
],
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": true
},
"web_accessible_resources": ["jsui.js"]
}
```

**Content Script**

```
window.onload = function () {
var elm = document.getElementById("my-container");
if (elm != undefined && elm != null) {
    //alert("Main Page LOADED!!!");        
}
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.clickit == "yes") {
    performclick();
}    
});
function performclick() { 
//document.URL is always the same  
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
if (links.length) {
    var linkToClick = links[1];
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');

    clickEvent.initEvent('click', true, true);
    linkToClick.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);        
}
}
```

Update #1:

Silly me, it turns out that I was sending a message from my background script to my content script via the first tab.

I did my clicking decision in the background script than sends a signal to the content script so that the content script can do the actual clicking.

So since I was sending message from the background script to the content script in the 1st tab, it lead the `document` object to always belong to the first tab (i.e. main page).

Hope this helps someone, always check if you are doing messaging then check its logic.

Comment: Each web page has its own *instance* of your content script which means each content script's DOM is different (that is `document`, `window`, and so on).